# Setting AutoCAD ActiveSpace to ModelSpace VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I am trying to ensure that I am addressing entities in ModelSpace, but I get an exception that gives no hint at what the problem is because it's a COM object I guess. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? If I take out that line (and the zoom extents line) the remaining code works just fine, so I know my document object is being set correctly.

```
        Dim acDWG As AutoCAD.AcadDocument
        ' open the drawing
        acDWG = acApp.Documents.Open(dgvr.Cells("FullName").Value.ToString)
        ' ensure the drawing has the modelspace tab activated (doesnt work)
        acDWG.ActiveSpace = AutoCAD.AcActiveSpace.acModelSpace
        ' zoom to extents (sometimes works, sometimes not)                ' 
        acApp.ZoomExtents()
        ' build a selectionset of all blocks named 'Solid1' and then delete them all
        Dim ss As AutoCAD.AcadSelectionSet = acDWG.SelectionSets.Add("DELETE")
        Dim gpCode(1) As Int16
        Dim dataValue(1) As Object
        gpCode(0) = 0 : dataValue(0) = "Insert"
        gpCode(1) = 2 : dataValue(1) = "Solid1"
        ss.Select(AutoCAD.AcSelect.acSelectionSetAll,,, gpCode, dataValue)
        ss.Erase()
        ss.Delete()
        ss = Nothing
```

Update: I discovered why I am getting the error. The code is correct, but the problem is that the drawing has not completed opening yet. If I put a "wait for 5 seconds" line of code directly after the `Open` line, it works just fine. So it seems my question is how to open the drawing and have VB.Net wait for a signal from the COM object that it is "ready to continue"? (not sure how to word it)

Comment: From where are you running this code?

Comment: Inside Visual Studio .NET 2017

Comment: more specifically... WinForms

Comment: I dropped your code into a WinForms app and it ran with no exceptions.  Perhaps if you posted the exception you are receiving it would help us track down the issue.

Comment: If I put a `Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` after the `Open` line, it works... The drawing wasnt done opening I guess (large drawing file) - but that's not really the best way to solve the issue, right? (Question has been updated)

Comment: It may not be the best way, but if you don't mind the delay, it is the easiest way!  A better way would be to catch an event from AutoCAD, but since your code is out-of-process this may be tricky.  You could post this as a new question and see what response you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of `Do...Loop` and a `Try...Catch` block to "wait" like this:

```
            Dim acDWG As AutoCAD.AcadDocument
            acDWG = acApp.Documents.Open(dgvr.Cells("FullName").Value.ToString)
            Dim bOpen As Boolean = False
            Do Until bOpen = True
                Try
                    acDWG.ActiveSpace = AutoCAD.AcActiveSpace.acModelSpace
                    bOpen = True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' ignore the error and try again until it is open
                End Try
            Loop
```

Comment: Works like a charm, braX!! Thanks so much!